# How can I use a php parameter in HTML markup?

Tags: php, html, web

So I have tried researching this before jumping into asking this question. Given that I have an index.php, and a cookie which stores the username, saved as $name, most answers tell me its simple to do this:

```
echo '<h3>'.$name.'</h3>'
```

But this doesnt work for me, and I assume its because im doing strange syntax for an if statement first, and I want to use the parameter within this if statement. My exact code looks more like this:

```
<?php 
  //store the cookie
  $name=$_COOKIE['user'];
  //check that it is set
  if(isset($_COOKIE['user'])): 
    <section id="login">
      <h1> Welcome</h1>
      echo '<h3>'.$name.'</h3>';
    </section>
  else: //prompt to login
  endif;
?>
```

It is meant to show a welcome message to a user that is logged in, adressing them by name, otherwise prompt the user to login.

So my question is: **Why doesn't the parameter reflect at all? (shows nothing when the page is loaded) and How can I get this to work as intended?**

ps. Please don't worry about the security risk of using cookies to do this etc. It is purposefully vulnerable.

pps. I am 100% sure the cookie is set, I viewed it with a cookie browser.

Comment: your php is broken

Comment: That `if` part doesn't give you any errors?

Comment: You should turn on error reporting in your apache, then you will come to know syntax error in your code.

Comment: Or right after `<?php` write this code `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because the previous two lines are invalid PHP so it would throw an error and stop working.

If you want to use the `echo` approach then the correct syntax would be:

```
  echo '<section id="login">';
  echo '<h1> Welcome</h1>';
  echo '<h3>'.$name.'</h3>';
```

---

It is important to *never insert external data as if it were raw HTML*. This can render you vulnerable to XSS attacks. Treat the input as plain text and convert it to HTML before outputting it into an HTML document.

```
$name_html = htmlspecialchars($name);
echo '<section id="login">';
echo '<h1> Welcome</h1>';
echo '<h3>'.$name_html.'</h3>';
```

---

You can make the code easier to read by using variable interpolation:

```
$name_html = htmlspecialchars($name);
echo '<section id="login">';
echo '<h1> Welcome</h1>';
echo "<h3>$name_html</h3>";
```

---

And when outputting large chunks of HTML, it is easier to just drop out of PHP mode entirely:

```
$name_html = htmlspecialchars($name);
?>
<section id="login">
<h1> Welcome</h1>
<h3><?=$name_html?></h3>
<?php
```

---

**Aside**

Check to see if the cookie is set **before** you try to use it, not afterwards!

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['user'])): 
  $name=$_COOKIE['user'];
```

Comment: Never seen it like this before :-D `<?=$name_html?>` is that some sort of new alternative way of writing `<?php ?>`

Comment: @Stender — No. It isn't new (it was part of PHP when I learned it in the 90s) and it is equivalent to `<?php echo $name_html ?>`

Comment: @Stender it's short hand for `<?php echo` - but **warning** - this will only work if enabled in .ini

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs — Untrue. [The tag `<?=` is always available regardless of the short_open_tag ini setting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Comment: @Quentin but that depends on OP PHP version ;) but yeah as of php 5.4 short echo code is enabled, short codes still disabled

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs — Versions of PHP older than 5.6 are beyond End Of Life and no longer receive security updates. People using 5.4 need to upgrade, and not just for the certainty of `<?=` support.

Comment: @Quentin 100% agree but can't rule it out - some bespoke CMS systems are still on old version of PHP because it still works, same reason a lot of companies still used Windows XP when 7 came out for a few years or so - but yeah, everyone should upgrade

Comment: @Quentin Okay - So today i learned something new - so in a medium large application, will it have any speed improvements, or is it the same, and just preference based?

Answer (score 0):

you should use php + html like this:

```
<?php $var = 'my string'; ?>

<?php if ($var == 'my string') : ?>
    <h1><?php echo $var; ?></h1>
<?php endif;?>
```

this breaks up the if statement, allowing you to add html inbetween the conditional statement without having to echo and html from php

Answer (score 0):

You should post any errors you get - But your can't just write html inside php, without either echoing it out, or ending the php for a while.

```
<?php 
//store the cookie
$name=$_COOKIE['user'];
//check that it is set
  if(isset($_COOKIE['user'])):?> 
    <section id="login">
      <h1> Welcome</h1>
     <?php echo '<h3>'.$name.'</h3>'; ?>
    </section>
 <?php else: //prompt to login
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To display HTML code only if a php statement is true, just close the php tag right after you have opened the if statement and then put your HTML code between.

```
<?php 
    //store the cookie
    $name=$_COOKIE['user'];
    //check that it is set
    if(isset($_COOKIE['user'])) {
?>
<section id="login">
  <h1> Welcome</h1>
  <h3><?php echo $name; ?></h3>
</section>
<?php
   } else {
       echo 'Please login';
   }
?>
```